# Setting code style to open expression braclets in new line

Tags: intellij-idea

I have minor difficulties with Intellij default code styling. Intellij like to style methods that way

```
public void methodName(){
    ....
}
```

On the otherhand, I like my code as the following

```
public void methodName()
{
    ....
}
```

Every single time opening Intellij it reformat all code to the default code style and am need to change it back the way I like it, how can I change the code style setting for good?

Also, this is relevant to all expressions, loops and what so ever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Intellij idea 14.1.4, you can do following:

> File -> Settings -> Editor -> Code Style -> Java -> Wrapping and
>   Braces

Look for the:

> Braces Placement -> In Class Declaration
>
> Braces Placement -> In Method Declaration

There will be values, select Next Line